# Gridview with 2 SubItems possible?

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I'm just getting deeper to androids adapter and i'm wondering if it is possible to add a second SubItem for example a TextView. My Item-Layout-XML for the BasicAdapter which i use Looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/holderImg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/holderTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Am i right that my ImageView is the Item and my TextView is the SubItem? If it's true, is it possible to add a second Subitem which the Adapter can use? What i know is that the Adapter reuses the item's which dissapear from the Screen by Scrolling. So i can imagine that the really high sophisticated code behind an Adapter doesn't allow a second subitem because it's just developed for one Item-View with one SubView? Or am i completely wrong?

Adding a Picture of a GridView-Layout for better understanding:

[image: GridView - Item + SubItem]

Hope it is clear what i mean. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think what problem you are facing, it looks pretty simple, you can have any number of subitems in your GridView. If i am getting something wrong, please correct me

Comment: @mukesh rana Because if i add another textview subitem and implement it the same way i did it with the other items in the adapter i gett aResources not found exception string resource id #0x41.. But that's another point i don't want to confuse other user with this new question. I just wanted to get an overview if it is posdible. Thanks for your respond

Comment: `Am i right that my ImageView is the Item and my TextView is the SubItem?` **No**, they are both subitems of the layout root (in your case, the LinearLayout). **Yes**, you can add other subitems. `Adding a Picture of a GridView-Layout` This View looks like a **ListView**, instead.

Comment: @Mike still i am little confused but if you have any doubt regarding adding multiple items in gridview, then you can easily do that. If you tell me what problem you are facing while implementing this,only then i'll we able to provide perfect solution for you question

Comment: @MukeshRana You are righ't guys. figured it out it works now adding a second "SubView". Thank you

Comment: @Funkystein But it is a GridView. A GridView with unsetted num of Columns :) Just for this example. In real i'm Setting the Collums programmatically that's why it Looks like a ListView based on the xml

Comment: I see. Anyway, my comment remains valid.